# Jquery - Bootstrap datepicker, daysOfWeekDisabled not working on modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, datepicker, modal-dialog

I am using a `bootstrap modal` and a `bootstrap datepicker.`

On modal shown, it seems that the datepicker's `daysOfWeekDisabled` method not working a second time.

At the very first time it is working, but when i trigger the `modal shown` event again `datepicker` is not catching the second week day to be disabled on the datepicker. which is present in the modal.

The particular day is being picked via  an `ajax` call.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add some code

Comment: please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50481026/bootstrap-datepicker-daysofweekdisabled-not-working-when-using-modal